# Updating label text on changing datagridview cell value

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

Alloted hrs label is total hours alloted for each department and left hours is the hours left from subtracting alloted hrs at end of cell end edit.

Here in Datagridview, once i select value of department from dropdown list and enter value of tmh cell then on cellend edit row, i must update left hrs label text but i am not getting logic for this situation.

[image]

Here is my code

```
        #region THM CALCULATION.

        int column = ProjectActivitiesGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        string headerText = ProjectActivitiesGrid.Columns[column].HeaderText;

        DataGridViewRow d = this.ProjectActivitiesGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        String department = d.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

        if (department != null)
        {

            String chk = m_Project.projdepthrs.Where(c => c.DEPARTMENT == department).Select(c => c.DEPARTMENT).FirstOrDefault();

            if (chk == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill up department alloted hrs first");
                d.Cells[1].ReadOnly = true;
                d.Cells[2].ReadOnly = true;
                d.Cells[3].ReadOnly = true;
                d.Cells[4].ReadOnly = true;
                d.Cells[5].ReadOnly = true;
                d.Cells[6].ReadOnly = true;
                d.Cells[7].ReadOnly = true;

            }
            else
            {
                d.Cells[1].ReadOnly = false;
                d.Cells[2].ReadOnly = false;
                d.Cells[3].ReadOnly = false;
                d.Cells[4].ReadOnly = false;
                d.Cells[5].ReadOnly = false;
                d.Cells[6].ReadOnly = false;
                d.Cells[7].ReadOnly = false;

                String tmh = m_Project.projdepthrs.Where(c => c.DEPARTMENT == department).Select(c => c.TMH).First();
                LBLAllotedhrs.Text = tmh;
                LBLLefthrs.Text = tmh;
            }

            if (d.Cells[5].Value != null)
            {

                foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in ProjectActivitiesGrid.Rows)
                {
                    LBLLefthrs.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(LBLLefthrs.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(d.Cells[5].Value)).ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                LBLLefthrs.Text = "";
            }

        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("please select department");

        #endregion
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18703943/calculating-sum-on-similar-cell-value-in-datagridview