# Calculating Sum on similar cell value in datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

Here, in this `datagridview`, i want to caculate sum for similar departments.

That is if department is architecture on 1st row  and its `TMH` cell in below `datagridview` value is 36.

And then on 2nd row my department is design and its TMH cell value is 45.

And then again i have selected architecture department on 3rd row and its TMH value is now 45.

Here is my code

```
           private void ProjectActivitiesGrid_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Decimal sum = 0;

        #region THM CALCULATION.

        int column = ProjectActivitiesGrid.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        string headerText = ProjectActivitiesGrid.Columns[column].HeaderText;

        DataGridViewRow d = this.ProjectActivitiesGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        String department = d.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

            String chk = m_Project.projdepthrs.Where(c => c.DEPARTMENT == department).Select(c => c.DEPARTMENT).FirstOrDefault();

            if (chk == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill up department alloted hrs first");
                d.Cells[1].ReadOnly = true;
                d.Cells[2].ReadOnly = true;
                d.Cells[3].ReadOnly = true;
                d.Cells[4].ReadOnly = true;
                d.Cells[5].ReadOnly = true;
                d.Cells[6].ReadOnly = true;
                d.Cells[7].ReadOnly = true;

            }
            else
            {
                d.Cells[1].ReadOnly = false;
                d.Cells[2].ReadOnly = false;
                d.Cells[3].ReadOnly = false;
                d.Cells[4].ReadOnly = false;
                d.Cells[5].ReadOnly = false;
                d.Cells[6].ReadOnly = false;
                d.Cells[7].ReadOnly = false;

                String tmh = m_Project.projdepthrs.Where(c => c.DEPARTMENT == department).Select(c => c.TMH).First();
                LBLAllotedhrs.Text = tmh;
                LBLLefthrs.Text = tmh;
            }


               foreach (DataGridViewRow rw in ProjectActivitiesGrid.Rows)
               {
                       if (department == d.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
                           sum = sum + Convert.ToInt32(d.Cells[5].Value);
                       else
                           sum = 0;

               }
                LBLLefthrs.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(LBLLefthrs.Text) - Convert.ToInt32(sum)).ToString(); 

        #endregion


    }
```

Then if how can i get my sum as 36+45 for 1st and 3rd row having similar department dropdown list.

I want the logic for this situation.

Comment: Please add code of things that you've tried already.  A sample setup with values would also be very helpful.

Comment: Still issue is not resolved somebody there to help;

Comment: Where do you define `m_Project`?

Comment: m_project is my entity context...from which i am accessing table object.

Comment: So, if I am to reiterate your question, you want to query the `projdepthrs` table in your context for all the DEPARTMENTS that equal department and sum the values in the `TMH` column?

Comment: yes i want to sum tmh for matching departments if from dropdown i select different department then i must show tmh for that department

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37124/discussion-between-shanky-and-paqogomez)

Comment: Please be sure to mark as answer as well (click the little check mark below the number) Also nice is to "star" one of the entries in our chat session.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly, you want something like:

```
var result = m_Project.projdepthrs.Where(md=> md.DEPARTMENT == department)
                                    .Sum(ms=> Convert.ToInt32(ms.TMH));
```

Please comment if I have misunderstood.